# How to install Android studio version 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have finish installing the Android studio but it kept asking me for my Android sdk directory.

Comment: well, you need sdk for your app developement. you have to install sdks as well.

Comment: Ya I know but the config folder is there. But is refusing to install but I get it now. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the config from `C:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio4.0` folder. Start Android Studio, it will open a dialog about which parts of the SDK to download, and then proceeded as expected.